# Simple news ticker

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

So I have found a very [simple news ticker](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-news-ticker.html) that I would like to add to the top of my website. The installation instructions aren't very clear, all they say is:

> **Set Up
>
>   Just go to this file:
>
>   frontend/base/default/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml and call the "newsticker" block in the file after the license
>   and the newsticker will be displayed based on settings in admin.**

I just wondered if anybody here can provide clearer instructions, so I can get this up and running?

Comment: J Granty, has the answer provided by Siarhey solved your problem? Please mark the answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml` and insert the code at the top of the template:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newsticker'); ?>
```

Here is my template (base/default):

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 * .....
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('yantrakaar_newsticker/yantrakaar_newsticker_settings/enabled')) {
    echo $this->getChildHtml('newsticker');
}
?>
<?php if($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)): ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($crumbs as $_crumbName=>$_crumbInfo): ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $_crumbName ?>">
            <?php if($_crumbInfo['link']): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['title']) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></a>
            <?php elseif($_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
                <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(!$_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
                <span>/ </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Result:

[image: Result on homepage]

My Tickertext:

[image: Settings]

Possible, some js files was missed in the package:

[image]

If you has similar errors, just add files:

1. [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js)
2. [jquery.easing.1.3.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js)
3. [FitVids.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js)
4. [bxslider](https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4)

[image: Structure]

Result after:

[image]

In addition, I have added the jQuery.noConflict script to the layout (`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/newsticker.xml`).

Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/jquery.bxslider.css</name>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem" ifconfig="yantrakaar_newsticker/yantrakaar_newsticker_settings/jquery">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/newsticker/jquery-1.11.0.min.js</name>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem" ifconfig="yantrakaar_newsticker/yantrakaar_newsticker_easing/enabled">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/newsticker/jquery.easing.1.3.js</name>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem" ifconfig="yantrakaar_newsticker/yantrakaar_newsticker_vids/enabled">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/newsticker/jquery.fitvids.js</name>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/newsticker/jquery.bxslider.min.js</name>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/newsticker/jquery.noconflict.js</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <block name="newsticker" type="newsticker/newsticker" template="newsticker/newsticker.phtml" />
        </reference>        
    </default>
</layout>
```

Script (`skin/frontend/base/default/js/newsticker/jquery.noconflict.js`):

```
$.noConflict();
```

I hope it will help you.

PS: If you got an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" you can try the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I will give this a try...

Comment: @j_granty Good luck! :) If you have any questions, let me know, I will be glad to help you

Comment: I have managed to carry out your instructions and the news ticker now works! So thank you. The only problem is that I get a banner saying "Please stop hotlinking my easing script — use a real CDN instead." the link goes to: [link] (http://github.com/gdsmith/jquery.easing). 
Do I need to copy the contents of their "jquery.easing.js" file and overwrite my current copy?

Comment: Yes [link](https://blog.sucuri.net/2013/05/who-really-owns-your-website-please-stop-hotlinking-my-easing-script-use-a-real-cdn-instead.html)

Comment: @j_granty I have updated a link to the jQuery.easing file

Comment: Just one question. <br/>
The only issue now is the **jquery.noconflict.js** file. 
<br/>
**"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"**.
Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: @j_granty Try this solution [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal)